# How to create DYI female jumper cables from male cables?

Tags: electronics, cable

I just got a elctronics for Arduino/Raspberry Pi. The problem is that all the jumper cables included are male to male.

I know I could easily just buy more cables, but I'm wondering if any of you know a good way to build DYI female jumper cables using male ones as a base. 
That would be extreme useful for emergencies.

Answer (score 1):

Solder the two male ends of two cables together.  It is a dirty solution and you'll loose half of your cables, but you were talking about emergencies.

I suppose you could cut the male end off and replace it with a female header, but - because you'll probably have to go to the store for buying those headers - you'll better off buying new cables in that same store.

Over here those cables retail for about 15 a dollar.  M2M, M2F and F2F header pins with 5-20cm cable in all colors of the rainbow.  I know you were talking about DIY, but think about it...

Comment: Unfortunately they would still end up being male-male cables, but the upside is they would be twice as long!

Comment: Sorry!  You have M2M, I misread the original cables as being M2F...  FWIW sometimes there's connector/cables stuff to be found in old computer cases and/or electronics.